# How to pass the data from batch file to jython file

Tags: python, batch-file, jython

I am trying  to pass the data from batch file to jython file  and used in while creating webspehere queue connection factories. I am new to this Jythn scripting language. please help me to resolve this.

**Batch file :**

```
@rem create a JMS connection factories call %PROFILE_PATH%\bin\wsadmin -lang jython -f checkconn.jy %NODE_NAME% %SERVER_NAME% %QUEUE_MANAGERNAME% %QUEUE_HOSTNAME% %QUEUE_PORTNUMBER%
```

so i am passing below values from batch file to jython file :

The following options are passed to the scripting environment and are available as arguments that are stored in the argv variable:

```
"[MyServer7Node, MyServer7, QM_BFDC49, 127.0.0.1, 1416]"
```

My Jython code :

```
import sys

nodeName =sys.argv[0]
serverName =sys.argv[1]
queueManagername =sys.argv[2]
queueHostname =sys.argv[3]
queuePort=sys.argv[4]

def createconnectionFactories(nodeName,serverName,queueManagername,queueHostname,queuePort):
      print "Creating connection factories"
      ds = AdminConfig.getid("/Node:"+nodeName+"/Server:"+serverName+"/" )
      print queuePort
      AdminTask.createWMQConnectionFactory(ds,["-name ConnectionFactory -jndiName 'jms/ConnectionFactory' -type CF  -qmgrName '+queueManagername+' -wmqTransportType BINDINGS_THEN_CLIENT -qmgrHostname '+queueHostname+' -qmgrPortNumber '+queuePort+' -qmgrSvrconnChannel SYSTEM.AUTO.SVRCONN"])
      AdminTask.createWMQConnectionFactory(ds,["-name IntegrationConnectionFactory -jndiName 'jms/IntegrationConnectionFactory' -type CF  -qmgrName '+queueManagername+' -wmqTransportType BINDINGS_THEN_CLIENT -qmgrHostname '+queueHostname+' -qmgrPortNumber '+queuePort+' -qmgrSvrconnChannel SYSTEM.AUTO.SVRCONN"])
      AdminConfig.save()

 #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# Main program
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
createconnectionFactories(nodeName,serverName,queueManagername,queueHostname,queuePort)
```

When i am trying to run the script, i am not able to insert value for queueManagername, queueHostname, and queuePort.

Can some one tell me how i can pass user input value here in jython script?

Since '+queueManagername+' , '+queueHostname+' , '+queuePort+' is now working in this case.

Comment: As the syntax highlighting indicates you are not actually trying to interpolate your variables into your string. Check [the docs about string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) for examples of how to do it properly

Comment: Can you please tell me in my case How can i format the string so it can accept the values for queueManagername,queueHostname and queuePort

Comment: @UnholySheep : I am new to Jython scripting language

Comment: Hi All !! i am able to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

nodeName =sys.argv[0]
serverName =sys.argv[1]

def createconnectionFactories(nodeName,serverName):
      print "Creating connection factories"
      ds = AdminConfig.getid("/Node:"+nodeName+"/Server:"+serverName+"/" )
      AdminTask.createWMQConnectionFactory(ds,["-name ConnectionFactory -jndiName 'jms/ConnectionFactory' -type CF  -qmgrName QM_BFDC49 -wmqTransportType BINDINGS_THEN_CLIENT -qmgrHostname 127.0.1.1 -qmgrPortNumber 1416 -qmgrSvrconnChannel SYSTEM.AUTO.SVRCONN"])
      AdminTask.createWMQConnectionFactory(ds,["-name IntegrationConnectionFactory -jndiName 'jms/IntegrationConnectionFactory' -type CF  -qmgrName QM_BFDC49 -wmqTransportType BINDINGS_THEN_CLIENT -qmgrHostname 127.0.1.1 -qmgrPortNumber 1416 -qmgrSvrconnChannel SYSTEM.AUTO.SVRCONN"])
      AdminConfig.save()

 #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# Main program
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
createconnectionFactories(nodeName,serverName)
```